# iOS SSL certificate configuration for push notifications (Pushwoosh), error on generate

Tags: ios, cordova, ssl, pushwoosh

I'm working on a PhoneGap Build based app for iOS. Which uses Pushwoosh for the push notifications. Now I'm trying to configure the SSL certificate in the apple developer console for the production environment. I've already uploaded my app for review, but forgot to make the production SSL certificates for the push notifications.

To be more clear, under `AppId` I choose the `id` that I've used to build the app with, then went to create certificate for production and there I've uploaded my `.csr` file. There I get the following error:

> **An unspecified error occurred.**
>   *You already have a current APNs Production iOS certificate or a pending certificate request.*

My question is as follow: Does this mean I cannot configure the AppId for production pushnotifications while it is being reviewed by Apple? Or does it mean something else? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a lot of contact with Apple support, it appears to be a problem that multiple customers are having. They say it's high priority and are working on this issue, hopefully coming with a fix in the coming weeks.

[Edit] It seems to be fixed now! Was able to generate a certificate for the push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

the same issue i am suffering from. I believe this is due to the bugs from apple itself. I am also having almost 10 pending requests.

You can configure PushNotifications at the time of review.

Once all the pending requests get clear, we are able to create a fresh certificate and configure with the appid.

If you fail to configure, you cannot receive notifications on your app.
After adding build, if we didn't create APNs certificate, at the same time we will get message from apple saying about that, i think you haven't noticed.

Comment: Hey Sameer, thank you for the response, did the pending requests automatically disappeared? I'm not able to delete them myself. Or did you contact Apple?